# Emit couchbase data

Tags: couchbase

I would like to emit couchbase data in the following format :

```
rows: [
{
  id: "UniqueID",
  key: "UniqueKey",
doc: {
     meta: {
         id: "UniqueID"
      },
      json: {
           //ACTUAL DOCUMENT HERE
      }
    }
}
,
.... Second document and so on
```

When I try to create a view :

```
function (doc, meta) {  
  emit(meta.id, doc);
}
```

It emits the data in the following fashion :

```
total_rows: 55, -- DO NOT NEED THIS
rows: [
{
    id: "UniqueID",
    key: "UniqueKey",
    value: {
     //ACTUAL DOCUMENT HERE
    }
},
.... Second document and so on
```

How do I modify the view to output the exact same schema as mentioned above ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. View response follows a defined format that tools like the SDKs rely on for parsing.

Also it is generally not a good idea to emit the whole document: since the value of the view get stored in the secondary index, you are basically *duplicating all your data* in the key/value store and the view index...

View responses always include the document ID for a particular row, so you can always get the document by performing a key/value GET. The SDKs can also abstract that away in their API (eg. in Java there's a `document()` method on each row object).